# Why is there no compilation error on the line above the indicated line?

Tags: java, variables, compiler-construction, scope

I'm reading up on Java and I am scratching my head as to why `System.out.println("a: " + a);` does not yield a compilation error. Where is `a` ever initialized?

```
public class localVariableEx {
    public static int a;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int b;
        System.out.println("a: " + a);
        System.out.println("b: " + b);  //Compilation error
    }
}
```

Comment: `b`, by default is initialized to `0` (if uninitialized) as `int` is a primitive type. So it can't be a *compilation error* but a *warning* that your variable is unitialized.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, so if it is initialized to a default value, why is there a compilation error?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: sorry, but you're wrong: local variables are **not** automatically initialized. If you try to access them when they haven't definitely been assigned a value, then you'll get a compilation error.

Comment: I stand corrected, what I said earlier doesn't apply to local variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relevant rules of this are described in [the JLS § 4.12.5 Initial Values of Variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.12.5) (emphasis mine):

> - Each **class variable**, **instance variable**, or **array component** is initialized with a default value when it is created ([§15.9](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#41147), [§15.10](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#46168)): [...]
> - [...]
> - A **local variable** ([§14.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#5920), [§14.14](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#24588)) **must be explicitly given a value** before it is used, by either initialization ([§14.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#5920)) or assignment ([§15.26](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5281)), in a way that can be verified by the compiler using the rules for definite assignment ([§16](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/defAssign.html#25979)).

So while instance variables (such as `a`) automatically get a default value, local variables (such as `b`) don't get one and must not be used unless the compiler can verify that a value has been assigned to them.

Answer (score 8):

`b` is a variable defined in the method scope only, so the compiler can know that no one initialized it before, but `a` is a public variable that might be initialized somewhere else.

Comment: Tyler: As far as I understand, this is not the correct answer. see my answer below.

Comment: @Asaf, I am pretty sure this is correct. Stop "correct answer grubbing".

Comment: @Tyler: a _was_ initialized - when the object was initialized (with a default value). I'm here to learn, not just to answer. and Joachim did teach me something new.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is of a primitive type `int` which will get initialized immediately, which means:

**Static class members:** get init'ed when the class is loaded (most of the time, when the before `main()`, but it depends on when the class is loaded).

```
class S {
  static int a;
}
```

**Non-Static class members:** get init'ed when the object is. (most of the time after `new`, but there're other, more advanced, methods to new an object).

```
class S {
  int a;
}
```

**Local variables:** should be init'ed in the method's scope before first use.

```
class S {
  void foo() {
    int b = 0;
  }
}
```

**edited after being corrected...**

Comment: I did not write this code, it is from a website that I am reading. I am not sure why you explained the different types of variables, but thank you for your answer, though.

Comment: This is wrong. Local variables **will not be automatically initialized**! Unless you assign a value to them they don't have a value and the compiler will not allow you to read from them.